# Increasing the size of a input field in HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to increase the size of an input field on a webpage.  My width is fine, but my height is what I am trying to figure out.

```css
#searchBox {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="searchBox">
  <form action="search" id="searchBar">
    <input type="text" name="search">
  </form>
</div>
<!-- searchBox -->
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a height on the input?

Comment: Yes, I have tried adding css code to every tag/element for that block of code,  along with trying to manually add the css through the html tags.

Comment: `padding: 40px 20px` this modifies height and width seperatly

Comment: Really? Because setting the height seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9g6tpbox/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply increase the font size; the `input` will scale along with it.

```css
#searchBox {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}

#searchBox input {
  font-size: 200%;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="searchBox">
  <form action="search" id="searchBar">
    <input type="text" name="search">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This modifies the width as well though

Comment: While changing the font size does make the input taller, the OP didn't say that he wanted to change the font size, just the height.

Comment: @j08691 True. OP also didn't say they *didn't* want to change the font size. This is one approach; there are others. Feel free to post and/or vote for those.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do this. You may set the height with the attribute height inside the input, or change the height via css.

First Method:

```
<input type="text" name="search" height="200" />
```

Second Method:

```
input[name="search"] {
    height: 200px;
}
```

I prefer using the first one. Since it better expands to the text inside of it. But for using it multiple times, css is the way to go.

Also note that the first method might not work if you arent using any reset css or modernizer since browsers tend to overwrite/ignore the height attribute inside elements like inputs.