# Size of Google search box -

Tags: css

I found the code I need to embed into Google Sites to a add google search box, but I don't know how to make it larger. Can someone help me scale this up?

```
<form action="https://www.google.com/search" class="searchform" method="get" name="searchform" target="_blank">
<input name="sitesearch" type="hidden" value="example.com">
<input autocomplete="on" class="form-control search" name="q" placeholder="Search in example.com" required="required"  type="text">
<button class="button" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increasing the size of a input field in HTML/CSS/JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33238452/increasing-the-size-of-a-input-field-in-html-css-js)

Comment: What do you want to make larger? The form? The input field? Or what else?

Answer (score 1):

You could only add the `font-size` property in CSS

```css
.form-control.search {
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<form action="https://www.google.com/search" class="searchform" method="get" name="searchform" target="_blank">
<input name="sitesearch" type="hidden" value="example.com">
<input autocomplete="on" class="form-control search" name="q" placeholder="Search in example.com" required="required"  type="text">
<button class="button" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

or you can set a `width` and `height`

```css
.form-control.search {
    width: 80vw;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<form action="https://www.google.com/search" class="searchform" method="get" name="searchform" target="_blank">
<input name="sitesearch" type="hidden" value="example.com">
<input autocomplete="on" class="form-control search" name="q" placeholder="Search in example.com" required="required"  type="text">
<button class="button" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Obviously you can have a combination of both depending on what/how you want to make it larger.